# Over the Range Microwave not bolted from cupboard above

Tags: range, microwave-oven

My over the range microwave that came with the home I purchased 18 months ago blew up.  I purchased a new one, however, I can not figure out for the life of me how the old one was installed as it isn't bolted to the cupboards above??  I am completely stuck and need to get this old one out so that I can install the new one.  Any suggestions on how I may be able to get the old one out and how it may be installed, if not bolted from above?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without looking at it. Some have a mounting plate that attaches to the back wall and mounts from the side or from above. Some have a tray that gets mounted and the microwave slides in/onto the tray.

Answer (score 0):

Some older models attach through the sides. Look for screws through the cabinet frame that may be concealed by plastic caps, stickers, or the cabinet hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The one I installed was mounted on 2 vertical plates which I mounted to the wall and then I had to slide my microwave down into the slotted plates. Then I installed the overhead cabinet. I hate to say it, but you may need to remove the overhead cabinet first. Good luck!